# Howto use MSMP feature to send events to DAS

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-esb

We integrated WSO2 ESB & DAS, and we used ESB to send events to DAS by publishEvent mediator. For QoS reason, we want to use Message store-forward (MSMP - Message Store Message Processor) feature to send these events to DAS, but how to use this MSMP feature by publishEvent mediator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In publishEvent mediator[1], it will send messages to WSO2 DAS while creating streams with given details.

But in MSMP feature (Message Store Message Processor), it will store messages in store and forward (Within given time interval) to a given endpoint using processor[2]. It is a different scenario than publishing events to DAS.

Please understand different scenarios identified above and implement your scenario through that.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Publish+Event+Mediator

[2] http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/01/guaranteed-delivery-with-Message-Store-Message-Processor/